Execution Speed: Cython vs ctypes
I am learning about different ways to interface python and C. I have this function that takes the sum of integers between 0 and the function input. I've coded this function in python, cython, and C (interfaced using ctypes). Then, I timed the execution time using an input of 5000 and running the function 1000 times, and these were the results:

Python: ~0.2 s
Ctypes: ~0.01 s (~20x faster)
Cython: ~0.0013 s (~154x faster)

Cython is way faster than the ctypes approach (where I coded the C myself). What makes cython so much faster than the ctypes approach? I provide all the details below:
Python setup
example_py.py:
def sumTo(x):
    y = 0
    for i in range(x):
        y += i
    return y

Cython setup
example_cy.pyx:
cpdef int sumTo(int x):
    cdef int y = 0
    cdef int i
    for i in range(x):
        y += i
    return y

Setup file: setup.py:
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(ext_modules = cythonize('example_cy.pyx'))

Compile by running python setup.py build_ext --inplace.
C setup
example_C.h:
#ifndef EXAMPLE_C_
#define EXAMPLE_C_

int sumTo(int x);

#endif

example_C.c:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "example_C.h"

int sumTo(int x) {
    int y = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        y += i;
    }

    return y;
}

Compile by running gcc -shared -o libcalci.so -fPIC example_C.c.
Testing scripts
To test the ctypes approach, I ran this script:
import example_py
from ctypes import *
import time

numRuns = 1000
x = 5000

# Run test on python script
tic = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(numRuns):
    example_py.sumTo(x)
py_runtime = time.perf_counter() - tic

# Run test on c script
libCalc = CDLL("./libcalci.so")
tic = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(numRuns):
    libCalc.sumTo(x)
c_runtime = time.perf_counter() - tic

# Print results
print(py_runtime, c_runtime)
print('Ctypes is {}x faster'.format(py_runtime/c_runtime))

To test the cython approach, I ran this script:
import time
import example_cy
import example_py

numRuns = 1000
x = 5000

# Run test on python script
tic = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(numRuns):
    example_py.sumTo(x)
py_runtime = time.perf_counter() - tic

# Run test on c script
tic = time.perf_counter()
for i in range(numRuns):
    example_cy.sumTo(x)
c_runtime = time.perf_counter() - tic

# Print results
print(py_runtime, c_runtime)
print('Cython is {}x faster'.format(py_runtime/c_runtime))

Any thoughts on why ctypes approach is so much slower than the cython approach? Thank you for your time and wisdom!

Ahead-of-time compilation is always going to be (much!) faster than trying to comply with an ABI programatically from an interface that has to dynamically build and then decode a stack layout. That said, when you're calling larger / less-trivial functions, invocation overhead might not matter so much: this is a difference that only matters when you're making a lot of calls, since the overhead scales with the number of calls rather than being a percentage overhead.

Compilers can completely optimize out your loop since they know that the result is n*(n+1)/2. Clang does that but I am not sure GCC does it currently. I advise you to compute something less trivial. Besides, you did not enable optimization (-O3) and you really should for doing performance analysis. Measuring the performance of unoptimized code is nearly always a waste of time / useless. Enabling -mavx2 can also improve performance on x86 CPU at the expense of retro-compatibility (-march=native even more)

The overhead of ctypes should be few µs (especially here), maybe dozens in more complex cases or low-power CPU but clearly not ms. I thing you are comparing programs compiled very differently. Maybe one is optimized and not the other? By the way, I wonder if the first call can load pages of codes from your storage device which might be slow. It is better to call the target function once to avoid this overhead in all benchmarks.

I confirm the problem on my Ryzen 5700U. Default time (unoptimized): 9.1 ms. Optimized one (-O3): 0.89 ms. Very optimized one (-O3 -mavx2): 0.50 ms. Same with Clang: 0.27 ms. The last is 34 times faster than the default one!

Wow! Thanks, I'm less familiar with the different compiler flags for gcc, but I used the -O3 compiler flag you suggested for the ctypes approach got runtime that's 214x faster! Using -O3 -mavx2 made it 315x faster! So if I understand correctly, Cython does some optimization when it "cythonizes" the code. However, gcc does not optimize the code by default, but it will when you provide the right flags? Is there any reason not to provide the optimization flag for gcc?

It not much that Cython optimize the code but that the default optimization flag in the setup.py script used to compile the code (using typically GCC on Linux) should be either -O2 or -O3. Cython just translates the Python code to C. It let the C compilation step to mainstream compilers like GCC. As for why GCC does not optimize codes by default, please read this post (not that optimizer can in very-rare cases break some code and -O3 or -march=native can sometimes make it surprisingly slower because of a bad optimization approach).

Thanks to Jérôme Richard! The ctypes approach was resulting in tests slower than the cython approach since I wasn't using optimization flags when compiling the C code.
As mentioned above, using the -O3 flag sped the code from the ctypes approach up to 214x faster than python, using -O3 -mavx2 sped it up to 315x faster, and using -O3 -mavx2 -march=native sped it up to 325x faster.
